# Unity Editor log doesn't refresh due to "Information on used Assets is not available, since player data was not rebuilt."

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build

I'm reducing my build size using the Editor log to track which are currently the largest files contributing to build size. This was working, until suddenly I get -

```
Information on used Assets is not available, since player data was not rebuilt.
Do a clean build to view the Asset build report information.
```

Under the "build report" section of my Editor log, which no longer shows asset sizes. I have tried quitting Unity, reopening, clearing the log and rebuilding. How can I fix this?

Comment: havent tried it but did you turn off deterministic compilation?

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **File** > **Build Settings** and then click on **Player Settings**. In that window you can search for **Use Deterministic Compilation**. This works in Unity (2020.2).
That will allow you to Uncheck or Check the **Use Deterministic Compilation** option.

Comment: this is already checked

Comment: As I suggest try turning it off!! (sigh)

Comment: Turned off, didnt help

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a clean build.

Go to File > Build Settings. Click on the arrow right to the Build button then click on "Clean Build..."

Here's an image[image]